# How to put more than pending intent /actions in one notification?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I want to display a custom notification.
The notification will have a little refresh button on its right side. When a user clicks that button, notification is updated to newer information. And if a user clicks at any other place, then the actual pending intent gets fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want may be possible starting with Android 4.0.

Prior versions of Android did not support interactive widgets in the `RemoteViews` used in a `Notification`. While they worked for a handful of devices, they did not work for all of them and were not considered supported by Google.